# Rebind Radgrid does not refresh when radwindow closes

Tags: asp.net, telerik, master-pages, radgrid, radwindow

I am trying to rebind my grid once a radwindow has been closed through master page. My grid is in a usercontrol in aspx page. In master page i have :

```
 function CancelEdit() {
            GetRadWindow().Close();
        }

        function CloseAndRebind() {
            GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.refreshGrid(); // Call the function in parent page 
            GetRadWindow().close(); // Close the window 
        }

        function refreshGrid() {
                $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Rebind");
        }
```

and I have the following javascript in the user conrtrol:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function refreshGrid() {
        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(me.Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Rebind");
    }

</script>
```

Once I close update the database in radwindow i register a javascript:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mykey", "CloseAndRebind();", True)
```

I can see my data source changing but the grid doesn't get updated. any suggestions?

EDIT ::

```
The structure is something like this:

I have master page which has the RadAjaxManager.
There is a main page which has a user control
Another user control inside above user control which has the RadGrid
Then there is an aspx page that opens as radwindow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the client-side API to rebind your grid, should be the correct way to do that:

In your child page:

```
    function refreshGrid() {
        $find("<%= YourGrid.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
    }
```

To call a javascript function from the parent page, simply use this:

```
    function CloseAndRebind() {
        GetRadWindow().get_contentFrame().contentWindow.refreshGrid(); // Call the function in parent page 
        GetRadWindow().close(); // Close the window 
    }
```

Comment: changed user control's refreshgrid to this and still dont refresh

Comment: if the javascript is reached, then try using a RadAjaxManager to refresh the control.

Comment: I can see the refreshGrid() on master page being called but not on user control..

Comment: See the edited answer, you don't need a `refreshGrid` function in the parent page, only in the child page, which can then be accessed from the `GetRadWindow()` function.